# Any visualization software for the intrinsic metric of a convex polyhedron?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra, mathematical-software

I'd like to find a visual simulation of what it would be like to 'live' in a polyhedron with the intrinsic, piecewise-Euclidean length metric. Of course, to make it easier to visualize, I'd prefer to see a simulation of the polyhedron crossed with the real numbers or the circle.

I've seen Jeffrey Weeks Geometry Games, but I did not find any manifolds with cone points there. I've also watched 'Not Knot' several times, but while it shows what sight-lines to a cone point would look like, it doesn't show what the eye would 'see'.

I've sketched out several potential images myself, but software often reveals hidden features; for instance, A Slower Speed of Light showed me some very unusual features due to special relativity.

So, has anyone created an image of what someone living in a (potentially thickened) convex polyhedron with the intrinsic metric would see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe David Glickenstein's [GEOCAM](https://sites.google.com/site/geocamlab/Home) is exactly what you're interested in.

See his preprint ["A bug's eye view: the Riemannian exponential map on polyhedral surfaces"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06131).

> We explore the perspective of a bug living on the two-dimensional surface of a polyhedron. Images of various kinds of effects like lensing and cloaking are shown via color pictures of three viewpoints: the first person perspective of the bug, a map of the bug's viewpoint, and a look at the bug on the embedded polyhedron from a three-dimensional exterior viewer. The pictures were constructed by computing the exponential map of a polyhedron by cutting and rotating faces into the tangent plane of the bug.

Here's one representative image, but there are several more in the preprint, illustrating the phenomena of *cloaking*, *fracturing*, *apexing* and *lensing*.

[image: Figure 2 from the paper]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. I will accept it after a few more hours.